# Bundler creates a ? folder in the project's root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

whenever I run the bundle install command, bundler creates a directory in my projects root with the name '?'. How can I prevent this from happening?

I'm assuming the ? directory is due to the fact that some path has not been found, but which? And how could I tackle this issue?

Best regards,
DBA

Comment: Which version of bundler (use `bundle -v`)?

Comment: MacBookPro:~ dba$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-11 revision 28618) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
MacBookPro:~ dba$ bundle -v
Bundler version 0.9.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .bundle directory and running bundle install again seems to have solved the issue.